# Get Context Variable Value Api Manager Azure

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to get a value from one specific variable.

```
<set-variable name="userId" value="@{string authHeader = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "");string[] authHeaderParts = authHeader.Split(' ');Jwt jwt; authHeaderParts[1].TryParseJwt(out jwt);var user= jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("user-id", ""); return user;}"/>
```

And pass it into a SOAP request. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soap:Body>
                <TestSoap>
                    <TestBody>
                <user>@{context.Variables["userId"]</user>
        </TestSoap>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

How can i get the value from userId context variable?

Comment: Try `@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("userId"))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works this way for me:

```
<TestBody>
   <user>{{context.Variables["userId"]}}</user>
</TestBody>
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I use an approach with this notation

```
<set-body template="liquid">
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
      <TestSoap>
        <TestBody>
          <user>{{ context.Variables.userId }}</user>
        </TestBody>
      </TestSoap>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</set-body>
```